# Will React paint to browser DOM after each time render() function gets called?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following code, I have detected that the `render()` function gets called many many many times.

Just wondering: if the `render()` function gets called, will React really **paint to browser DOM** each time? (Just one performance concern)

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    console.log("React called render() function here, many many times");
    return <div> 
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Only if there is actually a difference between the current tree and the new tree. See https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html .

Comment: Not to the actual DOM but to a shadow dom to compare it to the old representation. You can improve the performance even more if you implement `shouldComponentUpdate()` where appropriate.

Comment: OK. Thanks. looks like the answer is no, since react holding its virtual dom and does not render if they are same

Comment: You need to determine why the render function is being called so frequently and fix that.  Add a specific `shouldComponentUpdate` function to reduce the number of re-renders.